# Is there any pray or suggestion in Islam to getting back on track?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, imaan

Here is the situation: My friend, once use to pray(salat) 5 times and fast and everything but now he even don't pray friday prayers. I try to understand why he has become like this. He doesn't listen to anyone, not parents or siblings. I was able to force him to pray with me one isha namaz(salat) but then he was too stubborn. I don't know why it is so. I want him as before.

Question is; What is the perspective of Islam on these situations? What can be done to change him for his better good? Is there any pray or suggestion in Islam?

Comment: This site not a supporting group, main purpose is defining what islam is and how islam defines things. So i edited your question that fit with rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assalamualaikum,

First of all, the BIGGEST mistake most muslims do these days, in guiding others is that they do not know that its ALLAH who guides people, its ALLAH who controls the hearts, we dont. Our job , according to Quran is only Tell them what is right , and that too in a very generous and soft manner.

Here are some of the verses about it:

> [64:11] No disaster strikes except by permission of Allah. And whoever
> believes in Allah - He will guide his heart. And Allah is Knowing of
> all things.

and

> “…Thus does Allah leave astray whom He wills and guides whom He wills.
> (Qur’an 74:31)

and

> Indeed, [O Muhammad], you do not guide whom you like, but Allah guides
> whom He wills. And He is most knowing of the [rightly] guided. (Qur’an
> 28:56)

So, dont assume that YOU will guide his heart, but just believe that your job is just to convey the message in most beautiful manner, As Allah says in Quran:

> 12.108 "Say: "This is my Way: I do invite unto Allah,- with certain knowledge, - I and whoever follows me. Glory to Allah, and never will I join gods with Allah!"
>
> 16.125 "Invite (all) to the Way of thy Lord with wisdom and beautiful preaching; and argue with them in ways that are best and most
> gracious: for thy Lord knows best, who have strayed from His Path, and
> who receive guidance."
>
> 22.67 "To every People have We appointed rites which they must follow: let them not then dispute with thee on the matter, but do invite
> (them) to thy Lord: for thou art assuredly on the Right Way."
>
> 28.87 "Let no one turn you away from Allah's revelations after they have been revealed to thee: and invite (men) to thy Lord, and be not
> of the company of those who join gods with Allah."

So, the point now is what you have to do.

First, you must not make him stubborn or remind him about prayer again and again. Most muslims do this mistake these days that they ask others to do those islamic acts, about which they are not even aware that WHY they have to do it. As he leaves prayer like this, then it means that he surely does not know that who is Allah, and what is value and benefits of prayer, and WHY exactly he has to pray. So your first job is NOT just to say him "you have to pray, you have to pray", but talk to him about value of Prayer. Casua;lly ask him questions like "Why do muslims pray", "What is reason beind praying", Arrange an Islamic quiz with him, and say "lets see who wins in it"

you just have to make sure that you do dawah to him, in a manner, in which he is most comfortable, because if you got harsh, said the same thing again and again, then instead of praying, he will RUN AWAY from prayer..

Prophet Muhammad said:

> “Make things easy for people and not difficult. Give people good news
> and bring them joy, and do not turn them away."

In the end , JUST keep praying to Allah in your own way, that May Allah guide him to right path.

Other than this, here are some tips, to do dawah to people:

http://www.a2youth.com/articles/islamic_manners/12_tips_for_muslim_youth/

Answer (score 2):

Try to talk with him, why he is not doing? You mentioned using force. Without giving background info which explains why we should pray and how merciful is Allah (c.c.), you can't expect him to do his pray. It becomes just surface, an empty attempt, meaningless body movements. Don't go harsh on him. Try to understand and do not say just you are going to hell stuff.

Other then making these actions with him, you can pray for his hidayah.

This is not a good answer(because , don't have any references) but a perspective.

Answer (score -2):

I have one suggestion
Tell his father to pray for him.I heard that allah will accept the pray of father for his son.
If he cooperate tell him to say dhikkar(alhamdullilla,allahu akbar etc) by keeping its meaning in his heart.